# how to pass parameter inside Strigbuilder class object?

Tags: asp.net

I am using

string strurl = "Reports/ReportFilter.aspx";

and bind a tag as

```
AnchorLeftMenuLinks.Append(" href='javascript:OpenDialogue(" + strurl + ");' ");
```

but it return error as "undefined object AuditReports" as runtime it become like

```
href="javascript:OpenDialogue(Reports/ReportFilter.aspx);"
```

but when i add single quotes manually in firebug like

```
href="javascript:OpenDialogue('Reports/ReportFilter.aspx');"
```

it works fine.
can anyone suggest me that how to add single quotes in code.Yhankx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
AnchorLeftMenuLinks.Append(" href='javascript:OpenDialogue(\"" + strurl + "\");' ");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var javascript = string.Format("href='javascript:OpenDialouge('{0}');'", strurl);
AnchorLeftMenuLinks.Append(javascript);
```

or:

```
AnchorLeftMenuLinks.AppendFormat("href='javascript:OpenDialouge('{0}');'", strurl);
```

Answer (score 0):

Reason behind it was Javascript String because In JavaScript, a string is started and stopped with either single or double quotes. This means that the string was being chopped to: `javascript:OpenDialogue(` and your function's syntax was being incorrect and thus it was not working.

Thus it was mandatory to place a backslash `(\)`before each double quote in `strurl`. This turns each double quote into a string literal.

There are some other special characters also which needed to be placed using `\`

- `\'` - single quote
- `\"` - Double Quote
- `\\` - BackSlash
- `\n` - new Line
- `\t` - tab